# Appium Mobile Gestures w3c Actions

Tags: appium-android

Can any one provide the latest W3C actions classes and related methods used for Appium Automation for Android device for Swipe Vertical and Horizontal and Tap

I have tried the Touch Action class and other methods but they are not working and i didn't find any documentations or related codes for latest W3c Actions which are using to Swipe and tap in Android Mobile Automation